# My Sprites seem to be spawning from left to right of the screen?

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, orthographic

So, my issue is that my sprites seem to be spawning from the left of the screen to the right of the screen (I'm using a samsung s3 to test my app). They should be coming down from the top of the screen. I'm using Libgdx and I know 0 starts at the bottom left.

Here's my code to set where they should start..

```
ublic class EntityManager {

private final Array<Entity> entities = new Array<Entity>();



public EntityManager(int amount){

    for(int i = 0; i< amount; i++) {
        float x = MathUtils.random (0, MainGame.WIDTH - TextureManager.ENEMY.getWidth());
        float y = MathUtils.random(MainGame.HEIGHT, MainGame.HEIGHT * 2);
        float speed = MathUtils.random(2, 5);
        addEntity(new Enemy(new Vector2 (x, y), new Vector2(0, - speed)));
```

Here is my MainGame Class...(well the top half of it)

```
public class MainGame implements ApplicationListener {
  public static int WIDTH = 480, HEIGHT = 800;
   private SpriteBatch batch;
```

Heres my orthocamera set up (top half)

```
 public OrthoCamera() {
    this(new VirtualViewport(MainGame.WIDTH, MainGame.HEIGHT));
```

Heres my full OrthoCamera class

```
public class OrthoCamera extends OrthographicCamera {

Vector3 tmp = new Vector3();
Vector2 origin = new Vector2();
VirtualViewport virtualViewport;
Vector2 pos = new Vector2();

public OrthoCamera() {
    this(new VirtualViewport(MainGame.WIDTH, MainGame.HEIGHT));
}

public OrthoCamera(VirtualViewport virtualViewport) {
    this(virtualViewport, 0f, 0f);
}

public OrthoCamera(VirtualViewport virtualViewport, float cx, float cy) {
    this.virtualViewport = virtualViewport;
    this.origin.set(cx, cy);
}

public void setVirtualViewport(VirtualViewport virtualViewport) {
    this.virtualViewport = virtualViewport;
}

public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
    position.set(x - viewportWidth * origin.x, y - viewportHeight * origin.y, 0f);
    pos.set(x, y);
}

public Vector2 getPos() {
    return pos;
}

@Override
public void update() {
    float left = zoom * -viewportWidth / 2 + virtualViewport.getVirtualWidth() * origin.x;
    float right = zoom * viewportWidth / 2 + virtualViewport.getVirtualWidth() * origin.x;
    float top = zoom * viewportHeight / 2 + virtualViewport.getVirtualHeight() * origin.y;
    float bottom = zoom * -viewportHeight / 2 + virtualViewport.getVirtualHeight() * origin.y;

    projection.setToOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, Math.abs(near), Math.abs(far));
    view.setToLookAt(position, tmp.set(position).add(direction), up);
    combined.set(projection);
    Matrix4.mul(combined.val, view.val);
    invProjectionView.set(combined);
    Matrix4.inv(invProjectionView.val);
    frustum.update(invProjectionView);
}

/**
 * This must be called in ApplicationListener.resize() in order to correctly update the camera viewport. 
 */
public void updateViewport() {
    setToOrtho(false, virtualViewport.getWidth(), virtualViewport.getHeight());
}

public Vector2 unprojectCoordinates(float x, float y) {
    Vector3 rawtouch = new Vector3(x, y,0);
    unproject(rawtouch); 
    return new Vector2(rawtouch.x, rawtouch.y);
}

public void resize() {
    VirtualViewport virtualViewport = new VirtualViewport(MainGame.WIDTH, MainGame.HEIGHT);  
    setVirtualViewport(virtualViewport);  
    updateViewport();
  }
 }
```

And my full VirtualViewport class

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class VirtualViewport {  

float virtualWidth;  
float virtualHeight;  

public float getVirtualWidth() {  
    return virtualWidth;  
}  

public float getVirtualHeight() {  
    return virtualHeight;  
}  

public VirtualViewport(float virtualWidth, float virtualHeight) {  
    this(virtualWidth, virtualHeight, false);  
}  

public VirtualViewport(float virtualWidth, float virtualHeight, boolean shrink) {  
    this.virtualWidth = virtualWidth;  
    this.virtualHeight = virtualHeight;  
}  

public float getWidth() {  
    return getWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());  
}  

public float getHeight() {  
    return getHeight(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());  
}  

/** 
 * Returns the view port width to let all the virtual view port to be shown on the screen. 
 *  
 * @param screenWidth 
 *            The screen width. 
 * @param screenHeight 
 *            The screen Height. 
 */  
public float getWidth(float screenWidth, float screenHeight) {  
    float virtualAspect = virtualWidth / virtualHeight;  
    float aspect = screenWidth / screenHeight;  
    if (aspect > virtualAspect || (Math.abs(aspect - virtualAspect) < 0.01f)) {  
        return virtualHeight * aspect;  
    } else {  
        return virtualWidth;  
    }  
}  

/** 
 * Returns the view port height to let all the virtual view port to be shown on the screen. 
 *  
 * @param screenWidth 
 *            The screen width. 
 * @param screenHeight 
 *            The screen Height. 
 */  
public float getHeight(float screenWidth, float screenHeight) {  
    float virtualAspect = virtualWidth / virtualHeight;  
    float aspect = screenWidth / screenHeight;  
    if (aspect > virtualAspect || (Math.abs(aspect - virtualAspect) < 0.01f)) {  
        return virtualHeight;  
    } else {  
        return virtualWidth / aspect;  
    }  
}  

}
```

This is my Enemy Class (the objects that are supposed to be coming down)

```
public class Enemy extends Entity {

public Enemy(Vector2 pos, Vector2 direction) {
    super(TextureManager.ENEMY, pos, direction);

}

@Override
public void update() {
    pos.add(direction);

    if (pos.y <= - TextureManager.ENEMY.getHeight()){
        float x = MathUtils.random(0, MainGame.WIDTH - TextureManager. ENEMY.getWidth());
        pos.set(x, MainGame.HEIGHT);
    }

}



}
```

Comment: You did you setup your camera / viewport?

Comment: Yes. OrthoCamera and VirtualViewport - see edit for ortho

Comment: What is your virtualviewport class?

Comment: I just put up both virtual and ortho classes

Comment: ps. When I run it as a DESKTOP application it seems to have them come from top to bottom.Not the case when I run it with my ANDROID.

Comment: 1) Are you using the same resolution on desktop as you have on your android phone? 2) Why you are not using the libGDX viewport classes?

Comment: Ive been following a tutorial and they recommended this way. This is the link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rVS1zHThZ0

Comment: Edit - I added another class see code above.

Comment: That's a very deprecated way to use the viewports..

Comment: any suggestions as to why I'm getting them to come from left to right not from top to bottom?